# Unique Count (Excel VBA vs Formulas) Faster Approach

Tags: excel, unique, user-defined-functions, vba

32 Bit Excel 365 on 64 Bit Win7
Worksheet 300600 Rows x 105 Columns
Goal: Calculate the Number of Unique Entries in each Column

Attempted Solution 1: Formula

```
{=SUM(1/COUNTIF(A8:A300600,A8:A300600))}
```

Issue: Long Runtime, Freezes Excel, Must Stop Calculation

Attempted Solution 2: VBA UDF

```
Function UniqueCount(Selection As Range) As Integer
Dim UniqueArray()
ReDim UniqueArray(0 To Selection.Count)
Dim Rng As Range
Dim CUniqueCount As Integer
CUniqueCount = 0
For Each Rng In Selection
    For i = 0 To Selection.Count
        If UniqueArray(i) = Rng.Value Then Exit For
        If UniqueArray(i) = "" Then
            UniqueArray(i) = Rng.Value
            CUniqueCount = CUniqueCount + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Next
UniqueCount = CUniqueCount
End Function
```

Note: This is Much faster, but I'm still looking for an even faster approach

Comment: I have not, the reason I'm doing this is to break apart the dataset into smaller tables for upload into my access database -- the dataset it too large for access' memory constraints to break internally. I imagine I would reach these limitations with a pivot table as well. They're the same limitations I reach when applying the formulaic approach across all 105 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
'Set a reference to MS Scripting runtime ('Microsoft Scripting Runtime')
Function UniqueCount(SelRange As Range)
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each Rng In SelRange
        If Not dict.Exists(Rng.Value) Then
            dict.Add Rng.Value, 0
        End If
    Next Rng
    UniqueCount = dict.Count
    Set dict = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Interestingly, and in hindsight intuitively, the duration of the calculation is based more heavily on the number of unique matches found as that nested iteration compounds the selection iteration so our UDFs perform very similarly when there's a small number of unique values, but your performs MUCH better when there are a large number of unique values -- Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an array as well as the Dictionary:

```
Public Function CountUnique(rngInput As Range) As Double
    Dim rngCell               As Range
    Dim dData                 As Object
    Dim vData
    Dim x                     As Long
    Dim y                     As Long

    Set dData = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    vData = rngInput.Value2
    For x = LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1)
        For y = LBound(vData, 2) To UBound(vData, 2)
            If LenB(vData(x, y)) <> 0 Then dData(CStr(vData(x, y))) = Empty
        Next y
    Next x
    CountUnique = dData.Count
End Function
```