# UDFs Vs Built In Functions in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, performance, user-defined-functions

Is there a way to assess a speed comparison between UDFs, User-Defined-Functions, and Excel's built in functions without benchmark testing? A purely mathematical approach if you will.

For instance, I recently posted the following question:

[Unique Count (Excel VBA vs Formulas) Faster Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521389/unique-count-excel-vba-vs-formulas-faster-approach)

After writing the UDF it was obvious that it was much faster, but I frankly assumed it wouldn't have been, and am looking for clarity on how I can better align my judgement BEFORE writing vba that proves useless.

I found this:
[Speed, VBA VS Excel Formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263795/speed-vba-vs-excel-formulas) , but their question wasn't exactly the same as mine.

Comment: Without benchmarking, not really - but you can follow simple guidelines for improving performance, e.g. use arrays in memory, avoid loops etc. The main question you should always ask is whether VBA is even required. Sometimes using a few helper columns is much faster than a UDF - all comes down to design

Comment: I like the VBA for view-ability, a lot of my worksheets are viewed by a wide range of people. I used to use a lot of helper columns, but it was cluttered if they weren't hidden and obfuscated the calculation if they were; for my audience I found that a UDF with a meaningful name helped keep people from getting weeded in the minutia of calculations.

Comment: That said, you're hinting on a presumption that I've made -- when coding it is best to follow best practices, my presumption was that built-ins were designed employing these mechanisms - I've recently had cause to challenge that assumption.

What I'm slowly realizing is that Compounded or nested formulas, especially in indexed arrays seem to have more elegant UDF counterparts; but where that line is drawn between BIFs and UDFs is still very murky.

Comment: Unfortunately, as there is no way to view the source code for Excel's worksheet functions then the best we can do without benchmarking is assume, and we all know where that leads...